# символ " в запросе (C#)

Tags: c#

Как вставить код символа в запрос С#?
В месте, где я указываю на формат даты:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT top 1 task.[date_execute] FROM task where Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") = format(task.[date_execute], "dd.mm.yyyy") order by  task.[date_execute] asc;");
```

Comment: Либо экранировать (`"\""`) либо использовать одинарные кавычки.

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 1):

Для таких целей существует [экранирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2).
В каждом языке есть свой символ для этих целей, в C# это [обратный слеш](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256156(v=vs.120).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)(`\`).

Пример:

```
string valie = "Hello \"User\"";
```

Ваш запрос с экранированием будет такой:

```
"SELECT top 1 task.[date_execute] FROM task where Format(Now(), \"dd.mm.yyyy\") = format(task.[date_execute], \"dd.mm.yyyy\") order by task.[date_execute] asc ; "
```

---

Еще в большинстве случаев двойные кавычки можно заменить одинарной, но этот метод работает не везде!
Пример:

```
string valie = "Hello 'User'";
```